# Fitting middle div between header and footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a static footer(95px), static header(70px) and a dynamic middle div which is supposed to fill the gap what is left between them, so the middle is dynamic. I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

div.container {
    height: 98%;
}

header, .controls {
    text-align: center;
}
header{
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.controls {
  display: table;
  height: 95px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
}

#w1 {
    width:25%
}
#can
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#canTwo{
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;

}

#w2{
    width:50%;
border-top: 1px solid black;
}
#w3{ 
    width:25%;  
}

.side{
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    height: 77%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.hugetext {

    margin-left: 6px;
}

.side ul {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.controlbuttons {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.controlbuttons canvas {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
}

.side ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.big {

    border: 1px black solid;
    height: 77%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">

    <header>
     hi
</header>

<div class = "side">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class = "big">
  <div class = "hugetext">
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w1"><canvas id = "can" width = '0px' height = '0px'></div>
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w2"></div>
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w3"><canvas id = "canTwo" width = '0px' height = '0px'></div>
</div>

</div>
<script>



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   fitToContainer();
});
var canvas = document.getElementById("can"),
    ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rightCanvas = document.getElementById("canTwo"),
    rightCtx    = rightCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    control = document.getElementsByClassName("controlbuttons")[0];


function fitToContainer(){
    reoffset();


    function reoffset(){

        var h = control.clientHeight;
        var w = control.clientWidth;

        canvas.height = h;

        canvas.width = w;

        rightCanvas.height = h;

        rightCanvas.width = w;

        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        rightCtx.fillStyle = "green";
        rightCtx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }


}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zyjr3m2g/

The divs side & big are the middle part of the website.
I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

The problem is on smaller screens. The entire website should fit to the client window and even when you resize it should fit to the window by making the middle div smaller/bigger(depends if you minify or enlarge). there is not supposed to be any scrolling available as everything is visible. Is there a way to achieve this? I've been on this for hours with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
height center content = 100vh - (height header + height footer);
height: calc(100vh - (70px + 95px));
```

Example

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'segoe ui', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
  height: 70px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}

section {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - (70px + 95px));
}

section>aside,
section>article {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

section>aside {
  width: 25%;
}

footer {
  height: 95px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>header</header>
  <section>
    <article>content</article>
    <aside>sidebar</aside>
  </section>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to make <article> text not overflow <aside>, but move to the next line/create a interior scrolling effect?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use flex:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 70px;
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 165px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

main >:first-child {
  flex: 1 calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color: yellow;
  height: auto;
}

main >:last-child {
  flex: 1 200px;
  background-color: black;
  height: auto;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 95px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

I have used static height value for demonstration. If you like jsfiddle I did same here:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NightKn8/mydqq7zd/2/)

Comment: How can I make the black part(main:lastchild) 200px, and the yellow part(main first child) fill whatever is left?

Comment: This will kill responsive design but here you go [JSF](https://jsfiddle.net/NightKn8/mydqq7zd/2/) also updated my original answer.

Comment: Is it possible to make the first section not overflow with text the seocnd one, rather than create a new line? <section>a lot of text</section>

Comment: _I have used static height_ so you need to use % value on `body` like: `height: 100%`. Feel free to edit my code and discover new ways of flexing. Also use google and search for `CSS flex` to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code for your layout design.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
header {
    height:70px;
    background: #ccc;
}
footer {
    height: 90px;
    background: #ccc;
}
#container{
    height: calc(100% - 160px);
}
#content {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 305px);
}
#nav {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>Header</header>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="nav">Nav</div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>

</body>
</html>
```